# Conformal mapping in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a practice problem where we are given the map $f(u,v)$ such that $u=x^3 - 3xy^2$ and $v=3x^2y-y^3$.

We were first asked to compute the standard metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($dx^2 + dy^2$) in terms of {x,y} which wasn't a problem. However, the next part of the question asks us if the map is conformal without any other context. If anyone could explain how to show that the map is conformal (or not), that would be great!

Comment: You should know how to pull back the metric (or any covariant tensor). Do it. Do you get a functional multiple of $du^2+dv^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by a functional multiple of $du^2+dv^2$?

Comment: A function of $(u,v)$ multiplying that :)

Comment: Oh that helps! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. To add a question, do you recognize these functions from basic complex analysis?

Comment: At a glance, I can see that they satisfy the Riemann equations. Is this an important quality of the map?

Comment: It’s well-known that holomorphic maps are conformal away from zeroes of their derivatives.